# sql query to get data with multiple condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

table ta having three columns

```
A | B | C
1 |11| 0
1 |12| 0
1 |13| 0
2 |33| 5
2 |34| 10
2 |35| 78
5 |45| 0
5 |49| 0
5 |51| 0
8 |10| 0
8 |14| -1
8 |34| -2
```

I am looking the SQL query to fetch the distinct A value which is having C value ZERO for all the B .  (i.e the output would be 1 & 5)

Comment: Tag the database engine you are actually using. Mysql and sql server use different dialects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select a
from t
group by a
having min(c) = 0 and max(c) = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the average of C if it is 0 then all the C values are zero for B,

```
SELECT A 
FROM table
GROUP BY A
HAVING SUM(ABS(C))=0
```

Comment: And what does mod() do? Because it is not a tsql function.

Comment: Yes abs() must be fine.

Comment: Though `SUM(ABS(C)) = 0` is better.

Comment: Yes indeed will change

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

`select distinct A from [dbo].[table]  where A not in (
 select A from [dbo].[table] where C <> 0)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.c = 0 and
      not exists (select 1 from #tm t1 where t1.a = t.a and t1.c < 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select distinct a from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename 
  where 
    a = t.a
    and
    c <> 0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 Select 
 A
 from #tmp
 group by A 
 Having 
 count(*)=count(case when c=0 then 0 else null end)
```

Answer (score -1):

For SQL Server:

```
SELECT A FROM ta
EXCEPT
SELECT A FROM ta WHERE C <> 0
```